# Ошибка при объединении 2-х pdf (PyPDF2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь выполнить самое простое объединение двух pdf-файлов с помощью библиотеки `PyPDF2`, код:

```
directory = 'pdfs'
files = os.listdir(directory)
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for filename in files:
    merger.append(fileobj=open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'rb'))
merger.write(open(os.path.join(directory, 'book.pdf'), 'wb'))
```

Однако, вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\projects\mergePDF\merge.py", line 10, in <module>
    merger.append(fileobj=open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'rb'))
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 133, in merge
    pdfr = PdfFileReader(fileobj, strict=self.strict)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1689, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Гуглил по этой ошибке, но увы, все варианты решения проблемы к успеху не привели.

Comment: что происходит если вызывать: `pdfcat -o book.pdf pdfs\*`?

Comment: pdfcat -o **book**.pdf projects\mergePDF\pdfs\\*                                     
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (при это выделяет буквы, которые я обозначил полужирным)

Comment: это команда, которую следует в командной строчке выполнять (к тому же её вероятно нужно [тривиально] адаптировать чтобы она запустилась). Цель запуска: получить ошибку из вопроса.